# Scrollpane on the bottom, css is hacky, javascript is hard

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I want to put a bar on the bottom of my page containing a varying number of pictures, which (if wider than the page) can be scrolled left and right.

The page width is varying, and I want the pane to be 100% in width.

I was trying to do a trick by letting the middle div overflow and animate it's position with jquery.animate().

Like this:

[image: The supposed layout]

Here is a fiddle without the js: http://jsfiddle.net/SoonDead/DdPtv/7/

The problems are:

1. without declaring a large width to the items holder it will not overflow horizontally but vertically. Is this a good hack? (see the width: 9000px in the fiddle)
2. I only want to scroll the middle pane if it makes sense. For this I need to calculate the width of the overflowing items box (which should be the sum of the items' width inside), and the container of it with the overflow: hidden attribute. (this should be the width of the browser window minus the left and right buttons).

Is there a way to calculate the length of something in js without counting all of it's childrens length manually and sum it up?

Is there a way to get the width of the browser window? Is there a way to get a callback when the window is resized? I need to correct the panes position if the window suddenly widens (and the items are in a position that should not be allowed)

Since the window's width can vary I need to calculate on the fly if I can scroll left or right.

Can you help me with the javascript?

UPDATE: I have a followup question for this one: [Scroll a div vertically to a desired position using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069099/scroll-a-div-vertically-into-a-desired-position-using-jquery) Please help me solve that one too.

Comment: That's a lot of question marks for a single question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `#items` from

```
#items
{
    float: left;
    background: yellow;
    width: 9000px;
}
```

to

```
#items {
    background: yellow;
}
```

Then calculate the width very easily with jQuery

```
// #items width is calculated as the number of child .item elements multiplied by their outerWidth (width+padding+border)
$("#items").width(
    $(".item").length * $(".item").outerWidth()
);
```

and simply declare click events for the `#left` and `#right` elements

```
$("#left").click(function() {
    $("#middle").animate({
        scrollLeft: "-=50px"
    }, 'fast');
});

$("#right").click(function() {
    $("#middle").animate({
        scrollLeft: "+=50px"
    }, 'fast');
});
```

[jsFiddle link here](http://jsfiddle.net/ruisoftware/U6QdQ/4/)

**EDIT**

I overlooked that detail about the varying image widths. Here is the correct way to calculate the total width

```
var totalWidth = 0;
$(".item").each(function(index, value) {
    totalWidth += $(value).outerWidth();
});

$("#items").width(totalWidth);
```

Comment: This doesn't take into account variable width images

Comment: @CBRRacer Thanks for pointing that out. I overlooked that detail and made an update to my answer and to jsFiddle

Comment: This was the solution I chose as I created something similar myself.

Comment: Hey I have a followup question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069099/scroll-a-div-vertically-into-a-desired-position-using-jquery can you help me there?

Answer (score 3):

Use `white-space:nowrap` on the item container and `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to prevent the items from wrapping and to not need to calculate or set an explicit width.

**Edit:**: Here's a live working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vhvzq/2/

**HTML**

```html
<div class="hscroll">
  <ol>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
  </ol>
  <button class="left">&lt;</button>
  <button class="right">&gt;</button>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.hscroll { white-space:nowrap; position:relative }
.hscroll ol { overflow:hidden; margin:0; padding:0 }
.hscroll li { list-style-type:none; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle }
.hscroll button { position:absolute; height:100%; top:0; width:2em }
.hscroll .left { left:0 }
.hscroll .right { right:0 }
```

**JavaScript (using jQuery)**

```js
$('.hscroll').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  var scroller = $this.find('ol')[0];
  var timer,offset=15;
  function scrollLeft(){  scroller.scrollLeft -= offset; }
  function scrollRight(){ scroller.scrollLeft += offset; }
  function clearTimer(){ clearInterval(timer); }
  $this.find('.left').click(scrollLeft).mousedown(function(){
    timer = setInterval(scrollLeft,20);
  }).mouseup(clearTimer);
  $this.find('.right').click(scrollRight).mousedown(function(){
    timer = setInterval(scrollRight,20);
  }).mouseup(clearTimer);
});
```

Comment: nice I didn't even think about that

Comment: I ended up using this solution on one of my other projects, so big thanks for this!

Comment: Also I just noticed that this solution works especially well with responsive layouts.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Phrogz for this part -- give the image container the `white-space: nowrap;` and `display: inline-block;`.

You can calculate the width without having to calculate the width of the children every time but you will need to calculate the width of the children once.

```
//global variables
var currentWidth = 0;
var slideDistance = 0;
var totalSize = 0;
var dispWidth = (winWidth / 2); //this should get you the middle of the page -- see below
var spacing = 6; //padding or margins around the image element

$(Document).Ready(function() {
$("#Gallery li").each(function () {
    totalSize = totalSize + parseFloat($(this).children().attr("width"));// my images are wrapped in a list so I parse each li and get it's child
});

totalSpacing = (($("#Gallery li").siblings().length - 1) * spacing); //handles the margins between pictures
currentWidth = (parseFloat($("#Gallery li.pictureSelected").children().attr("width")) + spacing);
maxLeftScroll = (dispWidth - (totalSize + totalSpacing)); //determines how far left you can scroll
});

function NextImage() {
 currentWidth = currentWidth + (parseFloat($("#Gallery li.pictureSelected").next().children().attr("width")) + spacing); //gets the current width plus the width of the next image plus spacing.
 slideDistance = (dispWidth - currentWidth)
 $("#Gallery").animate({ left: slideDistance }, 700);
}
```

There is a way to get the browser window with in javascript (jQuery example).
and there is a way to catch the resize event.

```
var winWidth = $(window).width()
if (winWidth == null) {
winWidth = 50;
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    var winNewWidth = $(window).width();
    if (winWidth != winNewWidth) {
        window.clearTimeout(timerID);
        timerID = window.setInterval(function () { resizeWindow(false); }, 100);
    }
    winWidth = winNewWidth;
});
```

On my gallery there's actually quite a bit more but this should get you pointed in the right direction.